# How should I populate a MemoryCache without instantiating the object to be cached unneccesarily?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-evaluation, memorycache

The [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) class exposes a method called [.AddOrGetExisting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988741(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a threadsafe way to get if exists, and add if it doesn't exist.

This method returns `NULL` if the cached object didn't already exist. I think I understand the value of this because it provides feedback to the user regarding its existence in the cache.

My cache resolver looks like this:

```
private static T GetCachedCollection<T>(Guid cacheKey, Lazy<T> initializer)
{
    return (T) (MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(cacheKey.ToString(), initializer.Value, _policy) ?? initializer.Value);
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that the object is not created unless it is needed, and if it is needed I don't want to construct it twice.

The concern I have is that when I pass the `.Value` of my `Lazy` type as a parameter it may invoke the initializer regardless of whether the item is found in cache or not. However, if I understand JIT properly it will pass the delegate of the method and **not** invoke it.

How should I accomplish these goals:

1. Do not invoke the object initializer if it already exists in cache
2. If it is not in the cache then invoke it only one time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store the object in the cache, store the `Lazy`.

```
private static T GetCachedCollection<T>(Guid cacheKey, Lazy<T> initializer)
{
    var cachedValue = (Lazy<T>)(MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(
        cacheKey.ToString(), initializer, _policy) ?? initializer);
    return cachedValue.Value;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Not sure how I overlooked that!